# How do I change the color of a div with onclick by calling a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I put `this.style.background="#000";` inline in the div, like `onclick="this.style.background="#000";`, it works. However, if I put that in a function and call the function from the same onclick event, it doesn't work. However, if I make the function do something else (like bring up an alert box), it does work. What's going on?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
.tile {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="tile" onclick="myFunction()"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    this.style.background="#000000";
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Quick fix: `myFunction(this)`...`myFunction(x){x.style.`...

Comment: Advanced fix is to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 5):

I noticed you're including jQuery. You should strongly consider [separating your markup and JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). If you do go that route, here's what that would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
.tile {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="tile"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $(".tile").click(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
    });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/9/

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to do it this way you need to pass the reference of DIV element when you invoke your function. During execution of your onclick handler "this" will reference to the current element. Pass it as an argument!

Here is the corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
.tile {
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
background-color:red;
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="tile" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>

<script>
function myFunction(divObj) {
    divObj.style.background="#000000";
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One more note: I see you are loading jquery. If you do so, why don't you use that? At least for changing the color... In your function you should use (check the jquery reference, but probably this is OK) $(divObj).css({backgroundColor: '#000000'})

Comment: how were you able to fix the code formatting? :-) didn't work for me... although I used 4spaces correctly (theoretically..) :-) Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="tile" onclick="myFunction(this)"></div>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.style.background="#000000";
}
</script>
```